# Popular Post Not Show

Tags: php, functions

I have code in function and plugin widget, please see my code below.

`function.php` //show count

```
function hwd_post_views(){
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$n = get_post_meta($post_id, $count_key, true);
if ($n > 999999999) {
    $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000000, 1) . 'B';
} else if ($n > 999999) {
    $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000, 1) . 'M';
} else if ($n > 999) {
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000, 1) . 'K';
} else {
    $n_format = $n;
} echo $n_format;}
```

`Widget-pop.php` //Plugin Show Popular Post

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Popular Posts Widget
 */

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'hwd_pop_load_widgets' );

function hwd_pop_load_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'hwd_pop_widget' );
}

class hwd_pop_widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Widget setup.
     */
    function hwd_pop_widget() {
        /* Widget settings. */
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'hwd_pop_widget', 'description' => __('A widget that displays a list of popular posts within a time period of your choice.', 'hwd-text') );

        /* Widget control settings. */
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 250, 'height' => 300, 'id_base' => 'hwd_pop_widget' );

        /* Create the widget. */
        $this->__construct( 'hwd_pop_widget', __('HWD: Popular Posts Widget', 'hwd-text'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    }

    /**
     * How to display the widget on the screen.
     */
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );

        /* Our variables from the widget settings. */
        global $post;
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $popular_days = $instance['popular_days'];
        $number = $instance['number'];

        /* Before widget (defined by themes). */
        echo $before_widget;

        /* Display the widget title if one was input (before and after defined by themes). */
        if ( $title )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

        ?>

        <div id="terpopuler" class="terpopuler__row">
            <ul class="terpopuler__wrap">
                <?php $i = 0; $popular_days_ago = '$popular_days days ago'; $recent = new WP_Query(array( 'posts_per_page' => $number, 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC', 'meta_key' => 'post_views_count', 'date_query' => array( array( 'after' => $popular_days_ago )) )); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
                <li class="terpopuler__item">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                        <div class="terpopuler__num"><?php $i++; echo $i ?></div>
                        <div class="terpopuler__title">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <?php $post_views = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_views_count', true); if ( $post_views >= 1) { ?>
                            <span class="terpopuler__info"><?php hwd_post_views(); ?> kali dibaca</span>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
        </div><!--widget-terpopuler-->

        <?php

        /* After widget (defined by themes). */
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    /**
     * Update the widget settings.
     */
    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        /* Strip tags for title and name to remove HTML (important for text inputs). */
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['popular_days'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['popular_days'] );
        $instance['number'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['number'] );

        return $instance;
    }


    function form( $instance ) {

        /* Set up some default widget settings. */
        $defaults = array( 'title' => 'Title', 'number' => 5, 'popular_days' => 30 );
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>

        <!-- Widget Title: Text Input -->
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">Title:</label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" style="width:90%;" />
        </p>

        <!-- Number of days -->
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'popular_days' ); ?>">Number of days to use for Trending topics:</label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'popular_days' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'popular_days' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['popular_days']; ?>" size="3" />
        </p>

        <!-- Number of posts -->
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>">Number of posts to display:</label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['number']; ?>" size="3" />
        </p>


    <?php
    }
}
```

See picture

[image: here]

I no understand, how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

My question not answer. I include file `widget-pop.php` to file `function.php` in my theme child.

if localhost (Xampp) it's work. Please see my site radarsulselcom

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Try this without **$i = 0;**

```
<?php $popular_days_ago = '$popular_days days ago'; $recent = new WP_Query(array( 'posts_per_page' => $number, 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC', 'meta_key' => 'post_views_count', 'date_query' => array( array( 'after' => $popular_days_ago )) )); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: not work. I use child theme from twentytwelve, Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I have a question about this: **$popular_days_ago = '$popular_days days ago'**

This shows popular posts published *days ago* but somebody knows how to show the most popular posts viewed in the last 24 hours no matter how many days ago a post was published like [popular posts plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/)? I mean, if a post was published **a month ago** but got viral in the **last day** and it's the most viewed of the last 24 hours, should appear in popular/trending posts but with **$popular_days_ago** only shows posts published in the time mentioned.